# Finding the value of the reference name to R

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I am doing some debugging in my application, mainly loading custom styles from styles.xml when my custom view is given a `style="@styles/CustomStyle"`, and attributes such as `custom:attribute="custom value"`

I looked into the `TextView` source to see how Android loads styles/attributes and I am mimicking that.  However I am not being passed any of my R.styleables through some of the calls to my constructors and so I am trying to peek in there to see which resources are coming in.

I am using `obtainStyledAttributes()` to load these key/value pairs into a `TypedArray`, however I am wondering if there is an easy way to convert the `R.styleable.CustomWidget_customAttribute` from the `int` that `R` reads, to its referenced name.

In essence, I want LogCat to say, "We've been given R.styleable.xxx" and not "We've been given 1487214712442"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this method: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getResourceName(int)

> Return the full name for a given resource identifier. This name is a single string of the form "package:type/entry".

Answer (score 0):

You most likely are not able to do this explicitly, as all resources are stored in a generated java class with no accessible reference to the original strings.

However, your best bet is override the toString() method for the R class.

See if something like that works.

Hope this helped!